# Getting error while installing Firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

I am trying to install @angular/fire using the following command

```
ng add @angular/fire@latest
```

but I was getting the following error. Tried different versions of firebase in the command but got the same error as the previous one. I can't figure out anything.

```
The package @angular/fire@latest will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: serene-chat@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!   @angular/fire@"7.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

Other information

```
Angular CLI: 16.0.2
Node: 18.16.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: linux x64
```

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1600.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.0.2
@angular-devkit/core            16.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.0.2
@angular/cli                    16.0.2
@angular/fire                   0.0.0
@schematics/angular             16.0.2
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.0.4
```

Comment: Angular does not do version 16 (right now), see: [Angular and Firebase versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire#:~:text=Angular%20and%20Firebase%20versions)

Comment: Then how can I install a supported version of Angular? @Luuk

Comment: Downgrade Angular to a version which is supported? (like 15) ?

Comment: Downgraded the Angular version to 14 and now it works.